# Seeding a database using Docker Mysql COPY fails

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

Using docker-compose and a build file, I am unable to COPY files to a mysql container. Here's the compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:

db:    
#image: mysql:5.7
build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile-mysql
environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: drupal
   MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal
   MYSQL_USER: drupal
   MYSQL_PASSWORD: drupal
#volumes:
#    - /var/lib/mysql
ports:
    - "3300:3306"
```

Then the Dockerfile-mysql:

```
FROM mysql:5.7
COPY ./drupal.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

I see no errors, and the file isn't there. The container starts up, mysql is good, all that, but NO FILE! Can someone point out what I've missed? I'm assuming after the .sql file is transferred to that directory, the .sql file will run as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. You have to run docker-compose build first to get docker to run any kind of COPY commands. If I understand it all correctly docker-compose build will create the containers, and docker-compose up will launch said containers.